# Conditional operations in each group

Tags: r

I have some groups of data and in each group there is one number that is a multiple of 7.

For each group, I want to subtract the first value from that multiple.

Reproducible example:

```
temp.df <- data.frame("temp" = c(48:55, 70:72, 93:99))
temp.df$group <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(temp.df$temp) > 1))
```

Expected result:

```
group 1: 49-48 = 1
group 2: 70-70 = 0
group 3: 98-93 = 5
```

Can you suggest me a way that do not require using any loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number divisible by 7 in each `group` and subtract it with first value.

This can be done in base R using `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(temp~group, temp.df, function(x) x[x %% 7 == 0] - x[1])

#  group temp
#1     1    1
#2     2    0
#3     3    5
```

You can also do this using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
temp.df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(temp = temp[temp %% 7 == 0] - first(temp))
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp.df)[, .(temp = temp[temp %% 7 == 0] - first(temp)), group]
```

Comment: The one with aggregate is working for the given problem. But in my original dataframe the result is coming in a list. Do you have any clue what may cause it? Its practically a similar dataframe with one additional column.

Comment: Probably that is because there are more than one number which is divisible by 7 in a group. You can use `x[which(x %% 7 == 0)[1]] - x[1]` to get first number divisible by 7.

Comment: I checked my data, there was no more than one number divisible by 7 but there are some groups with no number divisible by 7 which are causing the output to be a list. Can you suggest me a way to get rid of those groups before using aggregate function? Should I post it as a different problem?

Comment: I think you can use `temp.df1 <- subset(temp.df, ave(temp %% 7 == 0, group, FUN = any))` to remove those without a single number divisible by 7 and then use `temp.df1` in `aggregate`.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
temp.df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise(temp = temp[which.max(!temp %% 7)]  - first(temp))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  group  temp
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     1
#2     2     0
#3     3     5
```